# Highcharts labelname issues

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a problem with the Highcharts labels. I would like to display the text from database as is in the labels. So if the text is like `<labelName>`. I would like to display it as `<labelName>`. Also if the text is like `&lt;labelName&gt;` I would like to display it as is and not `<labelnme>` or `&amp;lt;labelName&amp;gt;` Currently I am gettiing the values from PHP and is using `htmlentities` function for the names. 
It is working is the value in DB is `<ItemName>`, and displaying the same as Highcharts label. But if the name is like `&lt;ItemName&gt;` and I use htmlentities , it will show `&amp;lt;ItemName&amp;gt;`. If I add a condition which will apply `htmlentities` function if the tags are present, then it will be shown as `<ItemName>`

Comment: Add your code here, you can label formatter function .

Comment: How your data and chart configuration looks like ?